# How to get ALL user names from aspnet_users?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I am using the System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService for Form Based Authentication.

The authenication is done by .LoginAsync based on the user roles got by .GetRolesForCurrentUserAsync.

How to query the database to get a list of all users in the system?  I need the list to populate a combobox so the users can pick a contact within the system to connect to instead of simply typing the names and hoping for no typos.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to expose this information through your web service. Just make custom methods on your service that returns the data you need.

The Membership Provider is a common way to implement the interface to your database. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx. This certainly works good, though I find the provider often complicates things so just implement my own interface using the few methods I care about. Then just access the database however you are already doing (NHibernate, EF, LLBLGen, ADO.Net, etc).

Comment: Hi @toddles2000 Thanks for the suggestion.  It's exactly what I needed.  The membership provider and roleprovider do the trick just fine.  Cheers